# UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath and UITapGestureRecognizer conflicts

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

So I have a view in which it has some view which has a UITapGestureRecognizer on an image and I have a table view. The issue is that when I tap on a table view cell and the view which has a tap gesture recognizer on it is behind it, the action of that UITapGestureRecognizer is also executed. Question is how do I disable this so that when the table view didSelectRowAtIndexPath is executed the tap gesture recognizer action is not performed? By the way I have set :

```
 tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

I've also tried doing:

```
- (IBAction) handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender {

    if ([sender.view isKindOfClass:[TileViewController class]]){
        NSLog(@"CANCEL THIS");
    }

   if ([sender.view isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]){
        NSLog(@"CANCEL THIS");
    }
}
```

but it never went into the if statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're adding the tap gesture recognizer to the image, not the entire view or tableview.

```
[myImage addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also manage this by implementing `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` and using the view's class to determine what action to take.  This approach has the advantage of not masking taps in the region directly surrounding the table (these areas' views still descend from the UITableView instances, but they do not represent cells).

*Caveat: there is an assumption that Apple won't change the classname.*

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    return ![NSStringFromClass([touch.view class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellContentView"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
yourView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

on the view you're putting in the table cell. That should cancel touches on all child views. You can probably easily set it in your cellForRowAtIndexPath function.

Comment: that's not what I want, I want the didSelectRowAtIndexPath to be executed, but not the action of the tapGestureRecognizer

Comment: don't set it on the cell, set it on the subview you're adding to the cell.

Comment: I did.. so basically I have a subclass of UITableView cell and I set the userInteractionEnabled = NO after adding it to the subview

Comment: "I have a view in which it has some view which has a UITapGestureRecognizer on an image" perhaps you should edit this to accurately describe your code. So you have subclassed UITableViewCell and have an image in it with a gesture recognizer. Why not just remove the gesture rec when you set the row? You could also enumerate through all the subviews of the cell and set userInteractionEnabled to NO.